# Makefile: two targets from the same sources compiled twice with different flags

Tags: makefile

I'm building two targets from the same C source files - an executable and a shared library. The shared library requires the code to be relocatable (compiled with -fPIC), but I cannot use relocatable code in my executable for various reasons. Is there a standard/common way to handle this situation in a Makefile?

Comment: There are several ways. I'd say the cleanest is to have two directories for object files, one for standard objects and one for relocatable. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I agree with Beta, build all intermediate files, etc. to two separate directories.  That way, all Makefile targets have independent names (although you can of course use Make wildcards to avoid code duplication).

Comment: Thanks, guys! Would either of you care to write it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have two directories for object files, one for standard objects and one for relocatable objects. Something like this:

```
$(STANDARD_OBJS) = $(addprefix $(STANDARD_OBJS_DIR)/, $(OBJS))
$(RELOC_OBJS) = $(addprefix $(RELOC_OBJS_DIR)/, $(OBJS))

$(RELOC_OBJS_DIR)/%.o: CCFLAGS += -fPic
$(RELOC_OBJS_DIR)/%.o $(STANDARD_OBJS_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cc
    g++ $< -o $@
```

(There are more sophisticated variations, but this will get you started.)

Answer (score 0):

inject a few rules so that target of your binary build depends and uses static_lib.

shared_lib: whatever.so ...

static_lib: whatever.a ...

binary: static_lib