# Makefile: Only compiling half of targets at a time

Tags: makefile, pdflatex

I am compiling a LaTeX document using gnu make.  I have done that a lot in the past, but now I have a need to compile a document in two different formats, one for easy reading, ie for distribution, and one for easy revision.  As background to what I am doing, I have implemented [LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression) in my LaTeX file.  Here is an example of the file.

```
% TheTexFile.tex
% This accepts makefile definitions
%   \isTwoColumn
%   \isDoubleSpaced
\ifdefined\isTwoColumn
    \documentclass[letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\else
    \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\fi
%\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\ifdefined\isDoubleSpaced
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \doublespacing
\fi

\begin{document}
  Some document text for a document that should be able to be compiled using
  two different methods.  There seems to be a problem though, but OP thinks
  that it is in the makefile not in the LaTeX since it can be compiled using
  both methods by issuing the same commands that are in the makefile directly
  enter code here`from the command line.
\end{document}
```

I can get these to compile using different make targets, but am always sending people old versions because I have only compile one or the other, usually the easy to read one, and most people need to look at the other version, ie to make revision recommendations. I have followed the advice on the question [Makefile: two targets from the same sources compiled twice with different flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146216/makefile-two-targets-from-the-same-sources-compiled-twice-with-different-flags) with the exception that I would like to avoid using subdirectories if possible. With that in mind, I come up with the following makefile.

```
# The makefile

# The targets
OBJS=TheTexFile.pdf

# The different build methods
DBL_SPACE_PREFIX=DBL_SPACE_
TWO_COL_PREFIX=TWO_COL_
DBL_SPACE_OBJS=$(addprefix $(DBL_SPACE_PREFIX), $(OBJS))
TWO_COL_OBJS=$(addprefix $(TWO_COL_PREFIX), $(OBJS))

# A variable for defining the job information (output files)
JOBNAME=$(shell echo $@ | sed 's/\.pdf//')

all: $(TWO_COL_OBJS) $(DBL_SPACE_OBJS) clean

$(DBL_SPACE_PREFIX)%.pdf: TEXDEF=\def\isDoubleSpaced{1}
$(TWO_COL_PREFIX)%.pdf: TEXDEF=\def\isTwoColumn{1}

$(DBL_SPACE_PREFIX)%.pdf $(TWO_COL_PREFIX)%.pdf: %.tex

    pdflatex -jobname=$(JOBNAME) -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"
    pdflatex -jobname=$(JOBNAME) -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"
    bibtex $(JOBNAME)
    pdflatex -jobname=$(JOBNAME) -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"
    pdflatex -jobname=$(JOBNAME) -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    # Get rid of pdflatex files
    rm *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.log *.nav *.out *.snm *.toc

.PHONY: cleanall
cleanall:
    rm $(DBL_SPACE_OBJS) $(TWO_COL_OBJS)
```

This works almost perfectly.  The issue arises when I make sure that all targets are removed, ie issue the commands `make clean` and `make cleanall`, and then issue `make`. The first time, only the `TWO_COL_OBJS` are compiled.  If I leave all targets alone and reissue the command then the `DBL_SPACE_OBJS` are compiled.  Now I have all of the objects compiled, but I had to issue the same command twice which is what I wanted to avoid.

Similarly, if i reverse the target objects in `all`, ie

```
all: $(TWO_COL_OBJS) $(DBL_SPACE_OBJS) clean
```

becomes

```
all: $(DBL_SPACE_OBJS) $(TWO_COL_OBJS) clean
```

The I will get all of the `DBL_SPACE_OBJS` the first time and the `TWO_COL_OBJS` the second time.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you really don't want your `clean` rule to be a prerequisite of your `all` rule, do you?

Anyway, you can't do it this way.  A pattern rule with multiple targets means that the rule is run only ONCE.  It's run once and when it's run, it's going to build one main target and the rest of the targets built are side-effects.  Only the main target is checked against target-specific pattern variables, so the TEXDEF value will only be set to one of its values, which is why you only get one output.  Even if it WERE true that all the different targets would be checked against target-specific pattern variables, how do you expect make to know that for one of the commands you want one value and for the other command you want a different value?  If you think about it, this just is not possible.

Instead you have to make *two different* pattern rules, one to build each type of output.  You should write this (note you don't need JOBNAME anymore, but even if you did you don't need to use the shell just to remove a suffix...):

```
$(DBL_SPACE_PREFIX)%.pdf: %.tex
        pdflatex -jobname=$@ -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"
        bibtex $@
        pdflatex -jobname=$@ -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"

$(TWO_COL_PREFIX)%.pdf: %.tex
        pdflatex -jobname=$@ -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"
        bibtex $@
        pdflatex -jobname=$@ -shell-escape --enable-write18 "$(TEXDEF) \input{$<}"
```

If you want to combine these more you can put the recipe into a variable and just use that in both rules.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I was a little confused by your explanation, but once I figured it out, I updated your code so it is more clear what you are saying (at least to me).